# Process getting killed while running the program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run the personality trait repository of the sentinet. After a while the process is automatically getting killed. see the execution:

```
python process_data.py ./GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin ./essays.csv ./mairesse.csv
loading data... data loaded!
number of status: 2467
vocab size: 30391
max sentence length: 149
Killed
```

Here is the [process_data.py](https://github.com/SenticNet/personality-detection/blob/17c8703410ed0017ccbe2a17a943c5ec51d6be75/process_data.py#L1)

Kindly, let me know what I need to do to resolve this issue.

Comment: @vks The RAM was filled, but the process has also started using the Disk space. I think that is worth. What do you say? I have 1 TB disk space and 32 GB RAM.

Comment: @vks can you help me with the code. How is this made possible? I am familier with Theano but not with Pandas.

Comment: Does this line not splitting the data in 10 chunks each: `def build_data_cv(datafile, cv=10, clean_string=True):
    """
    Loads data and split into 10 folds.
    """`

Comment: While I was looking at the code I came across the issue. It is because of the Google Trained Vectors getting loaded. I guess it is not the issue of the dataframes. Is there a mechanism handy enough to load the vectors as per my memory configuration so that the program uses optimized memory.

Comment: :( oops... well, no worries. Thank you for your time. It helped me a lot.